# golang gorm reference two columns to same table, problem with insert

Tags: database, go, model, reference, go-gorm

original idea was to build rbac analog from yii https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rbac/migrations/schema-pgsql.sql

so, i have these two models:

```
type AuthItem struct {
    ID          uint   `gorm:"uniqueIndex;primaryKey;auto_increment;column:id" json:"id"`
    Name        string `gorm:"uniqueIndex;primaryKey;not null;type:varchar(64);column:name" json:"name"`
    ItemType    int64  `gorm:"type:smallint;not null;column:item_type" json:"item_type"`
    Description string `gorm:"size:255;column:description" json:"description"`
}

type AuthRelations struct {
    gorm.Model
    Parent AuthItem `gorm:"references:id;foreignKey:parent;column:parent" json:"parent"`
    Child  AuthItem `gorm:"references:id;foreignKey:child;column:child" json:"child"`
}
```

also i already have some data in auth_items table and i want to make insert into auth_relations table with GORM, and its looks like this:

```
var relation = models.AuthRelations{
    Parent: models.AuthItem{ID: 1},
    Child:  models.AuthItem{ID: 2},
}

err = db.Save(&relation).Error
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cant insert: %v", err)
}
```

i getting this error:

```
failed to set value 0x1 to field Parent; failed to set value 0x1 to field Parent
```

i tried to use gorm function Value(), something like:

```
func (item AuthItem) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return int64(item.ID), nil 
}
```

and after i implement this function db.Save works, but the constraints/foreignKeys/references stop working

**so my question**: is there any options to make relations like this in right way or how can i use value() function without loosing constraints ?

Comment: based on the link below, the `foreignKey` attribute should be ID for both fields, and the `references` attribute should be `parent` and `child`, respectively (if `parent` and `child` are columns in the `auth_relations` table).
https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html#Override-References

Comment: then gorm cant read tags correctly and results into error:

`CREATE TABLE "auth_relations" ("id" bigserial,"created_at" timestamptz,"updated_at" timestamptz,"deleted_at" timestamptz,"parent" ,"child" ,PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`

`ERROR: syntax error at or near "," (SQLSTATE 42601) `

because reference reads type of structure member/gorm column, and if ill set type for column it will kill constraints too

Comment: also i think that relation should be "belongs-to" like here https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html

Comment: @IlyaVasilev please attach sample data for `yii` rbac.

Comment: @Chandan here how it works in yii [yii_rbac](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization)
|
so in `AuthItems` table how i see should be records like
|
`1 test_role 0 "test role"`
`2 test_rights_to_create 1 "right to create something"`
|
and in `AuthRelations` records should point where is parent role or group and what child rights they have

Comment: @IlyaVasilev please check the answer and let me know if the explanation is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came to conclusion that i need to use many2many relation and here is example for case:

```
type AuthItem struct {
    ID          uint      `gorm:"uniqueIndex;primaryKey;auto_increment" json:"id"`
    Name        string    `gorm:"unique;not null;type:varchar(64);column:name" json:"name"`
    ItemType    int64     `gorm:"type:smallint;not null;column:item_type" json:"item_type"`
    Description string    `gorm:"size:255;column:description" json:"description"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:null" json:"deleted_at"`
}

type AuthRelations struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"uniqueIndex;primaryKey;auto_increment" json:"id"`
    Parent    []AuthItem `gorm:"many2many:prnt_authitem_parent;References:Name;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;" json:"parent"`
    Child     []AuthItem `gorm:"many2many:chld_authitem_child;References:Name;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;" json:"child"`
    CreatedAt time.Time  `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time  `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt time.Time  `gorm:"default:null" json:"deleted_at"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relation is more near to `one-to-many` or `many-to-many` has one parent can have multiple children's

Since we are referring to the same type as children we can update the model as below:

```golang
type AuthItem struct {
    ID          uint   `gorm:"primaryKey; column:id" json:"id"`
    Name        string `gorm:"primaryKey; not null; type:varchar(64); column:name" json:"name"`
    ItemType    int64  `gorm:"type:smallint; not null; column:item_type" json:"item_type"`
    Description string `gorm:"size:255; column:description" json:"description"`

    AuthRelations []AuthItem `gorm:"many2many:auth_relations; foreignKey:ID; joinForeignKey:Parent; References:ID; joinReferences:Child; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE"`
}
```

`AuthItem` can be inserted as

```golang
var relation = []AuthItem{
  {
    ID: 1,
    Name: "super",
    AuthRelations: []AuthItem{
      { ID: 2, Name: "admin" },
      { ID: 3, Name: "owner" },
    },
  }, {
    ID: 2,
    Name: "user",
    AuthRelations: []AuthItem{
      { ID: 3, Name: "normal" },
      { ID: 5, Name: "client" },
    },
  },
}
err = db.Save(&relation).Error
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("cant insert: %v", err)
}
log.Printf("Relation: %#v\n", &relation)
```

---

Same can be achieved with [`Self-Referential-Has-Many`](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Self-Referential-Has-Many) where we don't require second table and can use the same table with one extra column as reference

```golang
type AuthItem struct {
    ID          uint   `gorm:"primaryKey; column:id" json:"id"`
    Name        string `gorm:"primaryKey; not null; type:varchar(64); column:name" json:"name"`
    ItemType    int64  `gorm:"type:smallint; not null; column:item_type" json:"item_type"`
    Description string `gorm:"size:255; column:description" json:"description"`

    Parent *uint `gorm:"column: parent;" json:"parent"`
    AuthRelations []AuthItem `gorm:"foreignKey:Parent"; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE"`
}
```

we can insert record the same manner as we did before

Comment: finally I figured out how this shity ORM works. your answer is partially correct because it solves the problem but doesn't answer the question, so the answer is: use a many2many relation, it helps split the tables but creates additional ones, after all it is exactly what i wanted